# A Sequence from a Sequence

Tags: number-sequence

This is a sequence that I made. I poured by blood and sweat into this! OK, no, it was more like orange juice and yogurt. It wasn't really all that hard, I guess. It might be tricky to figure out, though! You'll know for sure when you've got it. Here's a fair warning, though, you're going to have to do some digging to confirm the 33rd term (that's the really big one).

```
0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 6, 4, 44, 1, 180, 42, 16, 1096, 7652, 13781, 8, 
24000, 119779, 458561, 152116956851941670912, 1054535, -53, 26, 27, 59, 
4806078, 2, 35792568, 3010349, 2387010102192469724605148123694256128, 2, 
0, -53, 43, 0, -4097, 173,...
```

I've given you the first 40 terms so there shouldn't be more than one possible answer. To help rule that out, though, I'll add this:

```
This is a finite list. You get an error if you try to get more than 52 terms.
```

Comment: Good job finding one OEIS did not have!

Comment: how do you define an error here?

Comment: An error means that the next term can not be found because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @EngineerToast something like domain restriction or invalidation of logic by the term? OK.

Comment: `"2387010102192469724605148123694256128";` 128, 256 hmm.. maybe...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next element is

> $37338$

Open **http://oeis.org/** , the world biggest database of known integer sequences.
You see that any sequence has an identifier number, for example the list of natural numbers is known as [**A000027**](http://oeis.org/A000027).

**How is Toast's list generated:**

> Starting from [**A000001**](https://oeis.org/A000001), we take the $i_{th}$ number of the A00000$i_{th}$ sequence to build our one.

As you can see, **[A000001](https://oeis.org/A000001)** starts with 0, so we consider 0 to build our sequence.
Then, we take the second number of **[A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002)**, which is 2.
Then, we consider the third number of **[A000003](https://oeis.org/A000003)**, which is 1.
And so on...

The next term in the sequence is **37338**, the 41th term of [**A000041**](https://oeis.org/A000041).
Toast's list has only 52 terms because **[A000053](https://oeis.org/A000053)** has only 29 numbers!

Comment: How in the world did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Do you really want to know? I admit it, I googled the big number! Ahah so smart!

Comment: Ahh! I didn't realize that it was already a sequence in OEIS! [A091967](http://oeis.org/A091967)

Comment: Except for some reason the first term is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @JoeZ. That's because the entry [A000000](https://oeis.org/A000000) doesn't exist.